# Linear recursions in finite fields

Tags: field-theory, recurrence-relations

Let $F$ be a finite field and let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be distinct nonzero elements of $F$.  Let $\alpha$ have order $r$ and let $\beta$ have order $s$.  Let $M = \operatorname{lcm}(r, s)$.  Let $a,b$ be nonzero elements of $F$ and define a sequence $u_n = a\alpha^n + b\beta^n$.

I have to show now that $M$ is the period of the sequence $u_n$, and I am choosing to show this by stating that there is no $L$, $1 \le L < M$ such that $u_{n+L} = u_n$ for all $n$.

I was warned that this is a challenging problem, so I am just wondering what my proof is missing because I found it pretty straight forward:

If $\operatorname{lcm}(r, s) = M$, then $u_{n + M} = a\alpha^{n + M} + b\beta^{n + M} = a\alpha^n\alpha^M + b\beta^n\beta^M = a\alpha^n + b\beta^n = u_n$.

Now suppose there does exist such an $L$ such that $u_{n+L} = a\alpha^{n + L} + b\beta^{n + L} = a\alpha^{n}\alpha^{L} + b\beta^{n}\beta^L = u_n$.  But $L < M$ and we know that $M$ is the smallest integer such that both $r|M$ and $s|M$, and we have a contradiction.

That's my proof.  Am I missing anything big?

Comment: You didn't show that $\alpha^L=\beta^L=1$, which is what you need to show that $r|M$ and $s|M$.

Comment: Consider the following. It is possible to select $a$ and $b$ in such a way that $u_1=u_2=1$ (solve the linear system of two unknowns and two equations to find them). Yet we cannot conclude that the sequence has period $L=1$. The conclusion is that somehow the proof must reflect the fact that $u_{n+L}=u_n$ holds for **all** $n$. Jgon already explained a huge leap you made. My line of objections shows that it is impossible to correctly reach the conclusion from the study of a single equation between the $u_i$:s. I'm afraid it looks like you haven't made any kind of a dent on this wall yet.

Comment: Thank you jgon and Jyrki.  Do you have any hints on how I can proceed?